# How to check a select element change when the element name is an array

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

What I am trying to achieve:

- My form consists of four fields of `#item`, `#unit`, `#price`, and `#total`.
- A user can input multiple lines of `#item` and `#unit`. For this, if the user clicks on "Add new line', there will appear a new line to receive user input for item and unit (quantity). If the user clicks on "-" on an already existing line, the line will be removed.
- Which item is selected is identified on real-time using javascript `change()`.
- The price of the selected item is dynamically retrieved using ajax and the price data is appended into the `#price` element and `#total` element is also filled up by calculating `#unit x #price`.

To achieve this, here's what I did.

First, my **HTML form** as below.

```
<form id="form">

    <input type="submit" name="create" value="Create" />


    <!-- dynamically add more lines -->
    <div class="form-group table-row hide" id="template">       

        <!-- remove button-->
        <div class="table-cell" style="width: 45px;">
            <a class="btn btn-default removeButton">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus">
                </span>
            </a>
        </div>

        <!-- user input: item -->
        <div class="table-cell">
            <select id="item" class="form-control">
                <option value=""></option>
                <option value="item-1">Item 1</option>
                <option value="item-2">Item 2</option>
                <option value="item-3">Item 3</option>
            </select>
        </div>

        <!-- user input: quantity -->
        <div class="table-cell">
            <input id="unit" min="1" step="1" value="1" type="number" class="form-control"  />
        </div>      

        <!-- price is dynamically filled up using ajax -->
        <div class="table-cell">
            <input id="price" type="text" class="form-control"  />
        </div>

        <!-- total is dynamically calculated -->
        <div class="table-cell">
            <input id="total" type="text" class="form-control" />
        </div>

    </div>

    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default addButton">Add new line</button>

</form>
```

And **javascript code to implement dynamic add/remove of input forms**.

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    var     idx = new Number( 0 );

    $('#form')

        // Add button click handler
        .on('click', '.addButton', function() {
            var $template = $('#template'),
                $clone    = $template
                                .clone()
                                .removeClass('hide')
                                .removeAttr('id')
                                .insertBefore($template);
            // assign name attributes with proper array name and index
            $clone.find('#item').attr('name', 'lines[' + idx + '][item]').attr('required', 'required').val('');
            $clone.find('#unit').attr('name', 'lines[' + idx + '][unit]').attr('required', 'required').val('');
            $clone.find('#price').attr('name', 'lines[' + idx + '][price]').attr('required', 'required').val('');
            $clone.find('#total').attr('name', 'lines[' + idx + '][total]').val('');

            idx = idx + 1;

        })

        // Remove button click handler
        .on('click', '.removeButton', function() {
            if (confirm("<?php _e( 'Are you sure you wish to remove this line? This cannot be undone.', 'doumi' ); ?>")) {
                var $row    = $(this).parents('.form-group');

                // Remove element containing the option
                $row.remove();
                idx = idx - 1;
            }
        });     

});
</script>
```

Lastly, **jQuery to call ajax**.

```
<script>

    /*  Get Item Price */
    jQuery('#item').change(function(){
        var $item_id=$('#item').val();

        var ajaxurl = '<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>';

        // call ajax
        jQuery("#price").empty();
        jQuery.ajax({
            url: ajaxurl,
            /* ******************************************************************** */
            /* ajax_get_item_price is a function that returns the price of the item */
            /* ******************************************************************** */
            data:' action=ajax_get_item_price&item_id='+$item_id,
            type:'GET',
             success:function(results) {
                jQuery("#price").append(results);
            }
        });
    });

</script>
```

I have no problem dynamically adding and removing lines for the input form.

The problem is that form elements in each line is given a name as an array like below;

```
<select id="item" name="lines[0][item]"></select>
<input id="unit" name="lines[0][unit]" />
<input id="price" name="lines[0][price]" />
<input id="total" name="lines[0][total]" />

<select id="item" name="lines[1][item]"></select>
<input id="unit" name="lines[1][unit]" />
<input id="price" name="lines[1][price]" />
<input id="total" name="lines[1][total]" />

<select id="item" name="lines[2][item]"></select>
<input id="unit" name="lines[2][unit]" />
<input id="price" name="lines[2][price]" />
<input id="total" name="lines[2][total]" />

...
...
...

<select id="item" name="lines[n][item]"></select>
<input id="unit" name="lines[n][unit]" />
<input id="price" name="lines[n][price]" />
<input id="total" name="lines[n][total]" />
```

I guess that since there are multiple `#item`s with varying names, jQuery does not know which `#item` it needs to pay attention to. However, I have no idea, either, as to how to properly call ajax with the concerned #item.

Any advice is highly appreciated.

Comment: Ids should be unique, use `class` instead. And use `context` for your `change` action, or something like `next()`.

Comment: u_mulder, thanks for the comment. However, I'm quite new to codes, and can you please elaborate a bit more for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, as I said, ids should be unique for a page, so for similar items you should use classes:

```
....
<select class="item" name="lines[2][item]"></select>
<input class="unit" name="lines[2][unit]" />
<input class="price" name="lines[2][price]" />
<input class="total" name="lines[2][total]" />
....
```

So, for `change` event use something like

```
jQuery('.item').change(function(){
    // to narrow the items, use this
    var this$ = $( this );
    // this$ contain exactly one item, which is currently changing
    // do stuff
});
```

No quite get what exactly wrong is happening, but I think you have too many items with `price` is and thus issuing prblems.
So this line does next: gets all `#price` elements and appends results to each of them.

```
success:function(results) {
    jQuery("#price").append(results);
}
```

You should clarify which `#price` item you exactly need. 
First, as I already mentioned - use classes for multiple similar fields `jQuery(".price")`
Second, add some clarification what field exactly should be updated.
There can be many ways, I show two

**One way**, use `next` function.

```
success:function(results) {
    this$.next('.price').eq(0).append(results);
    // here we refer to this$ - we try to find all `.price` element 
    // which come after our `select`
    // as there can be a lot of them we take only the first one
}
```

**Another way**, Use kind of `context`, ie some div, in bounds of which your elements are grouped.
I suggest changing your html like this

```
<div class="item-wrapper">
    <select class="item" name="lines[2][item]"></select>
    <input class="unit" name="lines[2][unit]" />
    <input class="price" name="lines[2][price]" />
    <input class="total" name="lines[2][total]" />
</div>
```

So, every block of your fields will be wrapped in a div.
After that we can tell jQUery to find `.price` element only in a div in which changed `select` is located

```
success:function(results) {
    var parent$ = this$.parent();   
    // again we refer to this$ getting its parent which is div
    parent$.find('.price').append(results);
    // here we try to find `.price` element located in a parent$ div. 
    // As it is definitely only one, we don't need to use any other code.
}
```

So, this is all that I can say)

Comment: Great. Nice and detailed step by step advice. I will try your advice soon, thank you!

Comment: Well...it works for manually written form elements, but doesn't work for dynamically added form elements. Say, `lines[0][]` are manually written form elements that shows up on default on page load. And `lines[1][]`, `lines[2][]`, ..., `lines[n][]` are dynamically added form elements when user clicks on "Add new line" button. `jQuery('.item').change(function()` works only for `lines[0][]`...

Comment: Okay, read about `on` binding for jquery, it should help - http://api.jquery.com/on/